# Matching query string vars with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, variables, mod-rewrite

I have URLs with the following query parameters:

```
/list.php?id=1&name=some-stuff.html
/list.php?id=18&name=some-another-stuff.html
```

How can I get them to look like this

```
/1-some-stuff.html
```

or even

```
/some-stuff.html
```

I tried the following lines but I get 404 error:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(\d+)&name=(\w+)
RewriteRule ^list.php /%1-%2? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Does 

`/1-some-stuff.html or even /some-stuff.html` uri exist?

Comment: Nope, I've made a typo and all I'm trying to get is to look them like "id-name". But server returns with not found error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the `new url` back to the `list.php` using an additional rule

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(\d+)&name=(\w+)
RewriteRule ^list.php /%1-%2? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^/]+)/?$ /list.php?id=$1&name=$2 [END]
```

EDIT : `END` flag does'nt work on all versions of apache ,if you are using apache version bellow 2.4, you can use the the following with `%{THE_REQUEST}`

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /list\.php\?id=(\d+)&name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^/]+)/?$ /list.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Hm, using [END] leads to 500 error on my server. I tried to use [L] at the end of the last line but got infinitie loop instead.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now but I had to delete slash before list.php?id=$1&name=$2.